# Can a discrete random variable be normally distributed?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

This question may seem quite strange, but I am wondering whether the above is true?

In several russian books I saw the notion of "somehow" normally distributed discrete r.v. Can this even be possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No. Sometimes you can approximate calculations by treating a discrete random variable as a normal random variable. For example, the percentage out of 1000 coin tosses that ended up heads.

Comment: I’ve not heard of such a notion, but clearly it isn’t possible in the literal sense.  Are you able to provide any examples where this term is used?  There are well-known phenomena that arise in number theory where an integer-valued function can be modeled by a normal distribution, but those are not even random variables, formally.

Comment: Quite a technical question, and not easy to answer.

Comment: I think the only situation where this might happen is if you consider a degenerate normal distribution. A random variable with such a distribution has zero variance and it is essentially a constant with probability $1$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> A [**discrete probability distribution**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Discrete_probability_distribution) is a probability distribution
> that can take on a *countable* number of values.

$$$$

> A [Normal Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) is a type of **continuous probability distribution** for a **real-valued random variable**.

$$$$

> A [continuous probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Continuous_probability_distribution)
> is a probability distribution whose **support** is an uncountable set,
> such as an interval in the real line.

$$$$

> In mathematics, the [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) of a real-valued function $f$ is the
> subset of the domain containing the elements which are not mapped to
> zero.

$$$$

Looking at the definitions of "continuous probability distribution" and "support", we see that the *domain* of a Normal distribution function must be uncountable, and therefore cannot be countable, which is what is required for it to be a discrete probability distribution, as in the first definition.

Answer (score 3):

The central limit theorem is applicable to discrete and continuous variables alike. In particular, the binomial distribution tends to a normal one as $n\to\infty$, and so may be called "almost normal".

Comment: But if, for example, when $n$ does not tend to $\infty$ the discrete r.v. can take only 3-5 values ($n < 30$), even though the mean of the data is equal to the median, can we classify such an r.v. as a normally distributed one by CLT?

Comment: The answer to OP's question is a clear NO.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It depends on what "somehow" is.

Answer (score 2):

The short and strict answer to your question is **no**. By definition, all normally distributed random variables are continuous random variables. A random variable cannot be continuous and discrete at the same time, so the definition excludes the existence of normally distributed discrete random variables.

---

The longer answer is "*It depends on what 'somehow' means*". There is a very famous theorem called the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) which tells you that random variables that can be written as the average of a large number of independent random variables will be "close" to a normal distribution.

In particular, if $X_i$ are independent variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma$, then we can define $\overline{X_n}=\frac{1}{n}(X_1+\cdots X_n)$, and the theorem tells us that $\sqrt{n}(\overline{X_n} - \mu)$ converges *in distribtution* to a normally distributed random variable with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$.